# How to Validate field value is getting changed or not

Tags: javascript, protractor

The Room total gets displayed based on the number of the guests added.My question is how to validate whether the value of the Room total is getting changed or not.If yes, how to print it in console.

Comment: You're going to have to give a little bit more details

Comment: code sample perhaps

Comment: Provide us some sample code. Read about [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello, you should provide more relevant information. We are not able to help you like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
browser.wait(function() {
    i++;
    return $('.popup-loading p').getText().then(function(content) {
        if (content != "the init value") {
            console.log("Value changed");
            return true;
        } else {
            _retryOnErr();
        }
    }, _retryOnErr);
}, 3600 * 1000, 'Error waiting for element present: ').
then(function(waitRetValue) {
    return waitRetValue;
}, function(err) {
    throw err + ' after ' + i + ' iterations.';
});
```

Comment: I have a model window where you can add or delete the Guest and based on that the Guest details with price gets populated with total price details. How to validate the Guest detail information based on the number of guest which is selected by user in the model window.